# app name doesn't appear in permission request alert

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePickerController to allow the user to pick images from the device.

When doing it the first time, I get a standard permission request alert, but the app name is missing..

[image]

I couldn't find any mention for this in the documentation.

```
 imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Other permission request (like location services) are displaying the app name appropriately.

Comment: Do you currently run the app on the simulator or on an actual device?

Comment: added the code. Runs in simulator (other permission requests work are displayed fine in the simulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason, bundle display name in info.plist was blank..

changed it back to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` and issue is solved