# When requesting deviceorientation permission on iOS13, the permission dialog doesn't show the app name

Tags: html, ios, ios13, user-permissions, device-orientation

I needed to get the device orientation, so I am using the `deviceorientation` event to detect that. Also I have the below code to get the permission:

```
if (DeviceOrientationEvent && typeof DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then((status) => {
        if (status === 'granted') {
            bindDeviceOrientationEvent();
        }
    });
} else {
    bindDeviceOrientationEvent();
}
```

But on iOS13, when this triggers the system permission popup, it doesn't show the app name in that. See the below screenshot:

[image: iOS13 orientation permission popup, doesn't show app name]

I read many articles and the used syntax are right only. But I am not sure why this happens? Can any one tell me the problem behind this or what I missed here?

Note: after I pressed the **Allow** button it works properly, and there is no issue on that.

**Edited:** similar to the below issue, but tried that suggested that also not works:
[app name doesn't appear in permission request alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581542/app-name-doesnt-appear-in-permission-request-alert)

Comment: You probably did not set up the right properties somewhere relatively to AppName. Inspect the properties carefully

Comment: In my plist I didn't see any property explicitly as AppName. But I have the 'Bundle display name' and 'Bundle name' properties which already set my App name. do you have any idea where we can check this AppName anymore?

Comment: I would have like to say anything related to app name, sorry. is this happening in the simulator or even no device?

Comment: got issue in the device only. and other permission popup works well, but this only triggered through HTML5

Comment: Looks like a bug...